# How to connect three traces in Altium as shown in the image?

Tags: altium, layout

I am making a PCB layout for a board and I want to make a trace similar to the one in the image. I have tried changing the angle options but it still doesn't work. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: Check out the teardrop generation function.

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Answer (score 2):

You should play with teardrops configuration, available in the "Tools" menu.

In your case that's the T-Junction that is interesting
[image]